# Using output from a function as input of other

Tags: python, loops, functional-programming

My software is a bunge of functions called in order:

```
function1 -> function2 -> function3 ....
```

They all receive the same input: a dictionary called `options`.

Sample:

```
def function1(options):
    # do something with options

def function2(options):
   # do other thing with options

def function3(options):
  # do other thing with options
```

Is there any tool to help me implement some sort of [Fluent Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)?

Currently i'm using a looping:

```
flow = [function1,
 function2,
 function3]

options = {}
for phase in flow:
    phase(options)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your current implementation is perfect based on the information mention in question.

Answer (score -1):

Is this something like what you're looking for?

https://mathieularose.com/function-composition-in-python/

```
def compose(*functions):
    return functools.reduce(lambda f, g: lambda x: f(g(x)), functions, lambda x: x)
```

Comment: Why to use this when writing the `for` loop is faster, efficient, clean and readable? (which OP is already using)

Comment: This won't work for the OP because all of those functions mutate the arg in-place, and return None, as is conventional for such functions in Python.